# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Custom client side validation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to implement a custom client side validation, but it is not working. I'm basing myself on the article on Codeproject http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275056/Custom-Client-Side-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC3

I also looked here on SO, but I think I'm implementing it in the correct manner, but I'm overlooking something.
My goal is to validate a date (required, date format and not earlier than another date on the form). The first two can be done with data annotations, the last I have to do with custom validation.

I have on my base class some dataannotations (ClassLibrary is in VB.NET):

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<MetadataType(GetType(CM_CONTRACTVALIDATIONData))>
Partial Public Class CM_CONTRACTACTIVATION
    '...
End Class

Public Class CM_CONTRACTVALIDATIONdata
'...
<DataType(DataType.Date)>
<Required()>
Public Property TakeBackDeviceWhen
'..
End Class
```

In the javascript file I have added the custom method:

```
//validation
$.validator.addMethod("checkPickupDate", function (value, element) {
    return false;
});
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        TakeBackDeviceWhen: {
            checkPickupDate: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        TakeBackDeviceWhen: {
            checkPickupDate: "Test"
        }
    }
}
);
```

My chtml file is as follow:

```
@Html.TextBox("TakeBackDeviceWhen", Model.TakeBackDeviceWhen.HasValue ? Model.TakeBackDeviceWhen.Value.ToShortDateString() : "", new { style = "Width: 200px" })
```

The resulting HTML is as follow:

```
<input id="TakeBackDeviceWhen" class="hasDatepicker" type="text" value="" style="Width: 200px" name="TakeBackDeviceWhen" data-val-required="The TakeBackDeviceWhen field is required." data-val="true">
```

It seems that neither my type validation and my custom validation isn't implemented.

What is going wrong?

Comment: I have been searching for this issue. I ended up in making a test MVC project. But it doesn't work either. Checked articles twice and I think I'm doing the same what they've been telling me. In this project I don't have a date check: http://www.4shared.com/zip/e9eb0Dza/TestMVC.html?refurl=d1url

Comment: OK. Found that DataType doesn't enforce a validation. Pro ASP.NET MVC3 Framework page 605: "■ Tip The DataType attribute can’t be used to validate user input—only to provide hints for rendering values
using the templated helpers (described in Chapter 16). So, for example, don’t expect the
DataType(DataType.EmailAddress) attribute to enforce a specific format."

Comment: Current status: (1) Don't use EditorFor, (2) add data_val, data_val_required, data_val_date as htmlattribute to the field, (3) DataType annotation will not force type validation. Still stuck on adding the custom jQuery validator. See http://www.4shared.com/zip/f9G2eNwu/TestMVC2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, solved it. I hope :-)

What did I learned today:
(1) Don't use EditorFor: when you scaffold it from a MVC template, input fields are generated to EditorFor, it seems that you can't add custom unobtrusive validation tags. So, I was trying to get this fixed, untill I changed it to TextBoxFor.

(2) You can add custom validation methods in jQuery, but you can't mix them with unobtrusive validation. After adding a custom method, you have to also add it to the unobtrusive adapters. And don't forget to add jQuery on the bottom :-s (I got this from [jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addMinMax round trips, doesn't work in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217009/jquery-validator-unobtrusive-adapters-addminmax-round-trips-doesnt-work-in-mvc))

```
$(function () {
$.validator.addMethod("checkpickupdate", function (value, element) {
    if (value == "20/09/2012") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("checkpickupdate");
} (jQuery));
```

(3) Add validation tags to the input field in the htmlAttributes:

```
@Html.TextBox("TakeBackDeviceWhen", Model.TakeBackDeviceWhen.HasValue ? Model.TakeBackDeviceWhen.Value.ToShortDateString() : "",
                new { 
                    style = "Width: 200px", 
                    data_val = "true", 
                    data_val_required = "verplicht!",
                    data_val_date = "moet datum zijn",
                    data_val_checkpickupdate = "wow"
                 })
```

(4) Datatype data annotations will not enforce a validation. You have to add it like in (3). You can add a custom ValidationAttribute like (for server side validation):

```
public class MustBeDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute {
    public override bool IsValid(object value) {
        try
        {
            DateTime dte = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString());
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the resulting html output:

```
<input type="text" value="" style="Width: 200px" name="TakeBackDeviceWhen" id="TakeBackDeviceWhen" data-val-required="required!" data-val-date="has to be a date" data-val-checkpickupdate="custom error" data-val="true" class="hasDatepicker valid">
```

As I'm using my ClassLibrary in different projects, I'm now going to try to seperate the dataannotations meta data from the class library (maybe with dependency resolver).